# How to make emacs to not format close brackets (keep it's indent)

Tags: emacs, formatting, elisp, code-formatting

for example when I write

```
fixlocale() {
    export LANG='en_US.UTF-8';
    export LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF-8';
}
```

and add close bracket it goes without indent but I don't like it, I'd like to indent closing brackets alike:

```
fixlocale() {
    export LANG='en_US.UTF-8';
    export LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF-8';
    }
```

not in bash only, I want to indent closing bracket everywhere in C, C++ too. How can I tell emacs to indent closing bracket aswell as code.

Comment: (c-set-offset 'substatement-close '+), does this work for you? I don't have a chance to try it right now I'm just throwing this out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C to get this to work I did

```
(c-set-offset 'substatement-open '+)
(c-set-offset 'defun-open '+)
```

This tells it to indent statements such as if, while, for.... and the second tells it to indent function definitions as well (not sure if you wanted for statements or functions so I gave both).

Comment: @Ash Can't seem to find a way to do it in bash. Braces don't seem to have a syntactic context in emacs (for shell script) and are set to default indentation (at least for functions, for statements sh-indent-after-open seems to work for some other stuff).

Answer (score 0):

in Shell-script mode, which is on by default, C-j from last semicolon will newline and indent as requested.

If already at that line and at wrong indent, a command `electric-brace' might do it. It's easy to implement: basically an (insert "}") followed by (indent-relative)

Comment: `(indent-according-to-mode)` will indent the closing brace back to column 0.

Comment: Indeed, which is an idiosyncrasy. It should behave as indent-relative does. Corrected my answer, thanks.